# Trace32: Way to set number of rows displayed on a data.dump

Tags: trace32

For a data.dump, you can set the number of columns of the window displayed with the /columns option, but is there a way to set the number of rows displayed?

If I dump out only 4 addresses, the window is quite large.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to limit the size of any window in TRACE32 use the command `WinPOS`.

E.g. if you want to have a `Data.dump` window at address D:0x100 with a hight of only two lines (one for the header and one for the content) use the following two commands:

```
WinPOS ,,,2.
Data.dump D:0x100
```

To skip also the header line use:

```
WinPOS ,,,1,,0
Data.dump D:0x100
```

You can also size the window like you like with the mouse, and then get the command to open the window exactly like that in you clipboard by using the command `ClipSTOre WinTOP`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a limited dump of addresses use the command `Data.dump` with an address range as a parameter.

E.g. if you want to see four 32-bit values starting at the address D:0x100 use the command

```
Data.dump D:0x100--0x10F
```

or

```
Data.dump D:0x100++15.
```

The second from means: Start address and the following number of bytes. (The dot after the 15 in my example indicates that 15 is a decimal number. Without the dot it will probably interpenetrated as a hexadecimal value.)

Comment: My issue is with window size. I can dump out addresses fine as you mentioned. I want to shrink the window to limited rows, eg 1 row if I dump out 4 long addresses, 2 for 8 etc